# Chocolaty packages not installing via OneGet/PackageManagement in Windows 10?

Tags: powershell, nuget, windows-10, chocolatey, dsc

I'm trying to use oneget w/chocolaty and it doesn't seem to be working at all. The package says it's installed, no warning or notification. It installs the package in the choco directory, **but doesn't run the install script and therefore the application is not actually installed.** Note this is Windows 10 (Powershell 5).

```
Get-PackageProvider –Name Chocolatey -ForceBootstrap
Set-PackageSource -Name chocolatey -Trusted 
Install-package filezilla -Verbose -Force -ProviderName chocolatey
```

yields

[image: powershell result from command]

[image: windows directory]

Comment: I don't know why, but if you don't previously set `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`, it won't work.

Comment: @yzT I had my execution policy set at Unrestricted, so that shouldn't matter? normally restrictions outright fail the install.

Comment: According to this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176961.aspx, it should work. Also I have noticed that some packages (e.g. Audacious) do not have a installer, but you can find the executable at `C:\Chocolatey\lib\package_name\bin\`

Comment: I fixed my issue by running `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` in PowerShell while running as an admin. Then `Uninstall-Package` followed by `Install-Package.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer - I wouldn't use the OneGet Chocolatey provider until you hear an official announcement that it is up to date and no longer using the early CTP preview that came out in April 2014 (not a typo).

Until then you should continue to use the official choco client.

Comment: Ouch.. I saw the provider prototype on GH, unfortunately I don't see a place to jump in.

Comment: You can jump into Gitter and chat about where you can jump in https://gitter.im/chocolatey/chocolatey-oneget

Comment: Joel, this was the answer yesterday. Not sure what kind of update you think there might be in one day. :)

Comment: I've been able to install ally my chocolatey packages using the OneGet package source. I think it's as official as it's going to get at this point

Comment: Thanks for the update Ken. We'll send out a note when the official one is available.

Comment: @FSCKur That's not relevant to this post.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, I also tried to fix the problem by running `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` in PowerShell, but I was still having problems with forbidden **TLS/SSL** security protocols.

And then (as [mentioned](https://chocolatey.org/install)) I tried through CMD-> `%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe`

and then in PowerShell :

`> Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePoin tManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net. WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))`

No more problems with TLS/SSL SecurityProtocol.