# How to install Node.js with Windows PowerShell PackageManager (OneGet)?

Tags: node.js, windows, powershell, oneget, windows-package-manager

I tried `Install-Package nodejs`, which seems to have done something:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Install-Package nodejs

The package(s) come(s) from a package source that is not marked as trusted.
Are you sure you want to install software from 'chocolatey'?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "N"): y

Name                           Version          Source           Summary
----                           -------          ------           -------
nodejs.install                 11.10.0          chocolatey       Node JS - Evented I/O for v8 JavaScript.
nodejs                         11.10.0          chocolatey       Node JS - Evented I/O for v8 JavaScript.
```

Then when I try to run the `node` command, it fails:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> node
node : The term 'node' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ node
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (node:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

How do I do it properly with `PackageManager`, so that the command is then available?

Not sure if this other question is related: [Chocolaty packages not installing via OneGet/PackageManagement in Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31714804/chocolaty-packages-not-installing-via-oneget-packagemanagement-in-windows-10)

As that other question suggests, I tried setting `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`, the uninstalling and reinstalling `nodejs`, but the result is the same.

I do see that after install the following files exist:

```
C:\Chocolatey\lib\nodejs.11.10.0\nodejs.11.10.0.nupkg
C:\Chocolatey\lib\nodejs.install.11.10.0.nupkg\nodejs.install.11.10.0.nupkg
C:\Chocolatey\lib\nodejs.install.11.10.0.nupkg\nodejs.install.11.10.0.nupkg
C:\Chocolatey\lib\nodejs.install.11.10.0.nupkg\nodejs.install.11.10.0.nupkg\legal\LICENSE.txt
C:\Chocolatey\lib\nodejs.install.11.10.0.nupkg\nodejs.install.11.10.0.nupkg\legal\VERIFICATION.txt
C:\Chocolatey\lib\nodejs.install.11.10.0.nupkg\nodejs.install.11.10.0.nupkg\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1
C:\Chocolatey\lib\nodejs.install.11.10.0.nupkg\nodejs.install.11.10.0.nupkg\tools\node-v11.10.0-x64.msi
C:\Chocolatey\lib\nodejs.install.11.10.0.nupkg\nodejs.install.11.10.0.nupkg\tools\node-v11.10.0-x86.msi
```

which makes me think that maybe it expects me to run the installer manually after?

My goal is to simply install anything I need on a new Windows machine from a script, without having to download/install them all manually with GUIs.

Comment: Is there any reason you are not downloading the official executable directly? Also, did you try the "nodejs" alias instead of "node"?

Comment: @MadWard I want to install everything I need on a new Windows system using a script. I'm just tired of manually downloading files and then manually running GUIs to install everything. It is slooooow. So now that I'm setting up a new Windows machine, I want to write a script as I go so that the next time it'll be a breeze (like I already have for Linux and macOS). I thought I could do it with the new builtin `PackageManager`, but if that proves to be too difficult, then I'll just go with choco if that's easier, but I wanted to try a builtin solution first.

Comment: Why not just [wget](https://4sysops.com/archives/use-powershell-to-download-a-file-with-http-https-and-ftp/) the .msi from official, say https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.15.1/node-v10.15.1-x64.msi , and use [msiexec](https://powershellexplained.com/2016-10-21-powershell-installing-msi-files/) to install?

Comment: @EricWong Well, I though `Install-Package nodejs` was supposed to be easy, that's why. I ended up switching to `choco` and installing stuff works. I don't want to write different setup instructions for each package, if I can have one command to install every package.

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me:

```
winget install nodejs
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reproduce this, but also was able to resolve it. The issue is that the `node` executable isn't on the PATH after installing with `Install-Package`. However, this does make some sense as the current PowerShell process won't pick up outside changes to environment variables until it is relaunched.

Chocolatey's `refreshenv` command works sometimes but not always, and after installing `nodejs` with `Install-Package`, `refreshenv` did not work to refresh the PATH variable. What *did* work was launching a new PowerShell session and running the `node` command, which ran the executable successfully:

```
> node

Welcome to Node.js v16.7.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
>
```

`choco.exe` can sometimes mask this but *usually* Chocolatey won't generate shims for executables placed by EXE or MSI installers (unless the package maintainer forcibly creates them).

> **Tip:** In case you are in a situation where you need to call the binary from the same process that installed the package (e.g. during a `chef-client` run where `refreshenv` isn't an option), use the fully-qualified path to the executable to invoke the newly-installed software.

---

Additionally, don't use the Chocolatey OneGet provider in real automation; it's not yet stable and looks like it [hasn't seen any development activity in five years](https://github.com/chocolatey-community/chocolatey-oneget) at this time of writing. From the `README.md`:

> NOTE: Seeking maintainers to help finish this Provider. Please inquire on the issues list or on Gitter (see the chat room below). Thanks!

There is an alternative listed in the same `README`:

> NOTE: For now, you may be more interested in using the ChocolateyGet provider as a stop gap solution until this provider is ready. See https://github.com/jianyunt/ChocolateyGet for details

I tried this and it seems to work, but I would still recommend using the official `choco.exe` binary. It's easy to install and you'll get the best support when using it. It's also telling that configuration management solutions (such as Chef's `chocolatey_package` resource) continue to make use of the binaries and will generally list installing the client as a prerequisite, even though technically the `PackageManagement` module could be used as a native solution instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this command on your powershell:

```bash
npm install -g npm
```

For further info refer to this URL:
https://www.webdevtutor.net/error-solutions/npm-the-term-npm-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet-function-script-file-or-operable-program

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34642985)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Try running : node.exe